# check get request is complete by JavaScript

Tags: javascript

A webpage is fully loaded.
There is an ajax request on this page that runs every 10 minutes.
The callback of this request **may take 2 seconds to 20 seconds**.
How can I make sure the request is complete with JavaScript?
**Note** that I want to add this code to the page and I do not have access to the website code.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use async

```js
const data = await axios.method('url',{json})
  .then(res => {//action})
  .catch(err => {//action})
```